# How to disable building dpdk shared libraries?

Tags: dpdk, ninja, meson-build

`CONFIG_RTE_BUILD_SHARED_LIB` option is no longer available in dpdk. By default when running meson build for dpdk. It is building the both static and shared libs. I'd like to disable building shared libs.

Earlier it was possible by setting `CONFIG_RTE_BUILD_SHARED_LIB=n` in `dpdk/config/common_base` , How do it with dpdk 22.11 lts release ?

TIA!